# Opening the print dialog from Typescript/ExpressJS

Tags: typescript, express, printing

I have a requirement, I have received a PDF from the server (typescript + expressJS) and able to display it to the user on the browser.

I need to launch window.print() after the pdf is displayed.

My current code looks something like

```
res.end(Buffer.from(body.toString('utf-8'), 'base64'));
```

I tried various options, but no use, the problem is that my response is directly from the server as a PDF and no control over the response.

I tried to alter the above code to

```
res.end(Buffer.from(body.toString('utf-8'), 'base64'), function(cb: any){
  window.print();
});
```

But I get an error

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

Is there a way to invoke the window.print()?

Update 1:

Tried just print() and got the following error

```
ReferenceError: print is not defined 
     at CorkedRequest.finish (_stream_writable.js:548:7)
     at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:388:3)
     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:20)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: `window` is not required, just use `print();`

Comment: @E730, thank's for the quick response, I still get an error 'ReferenceError: print is not defined'

Comment: Is the TypeScript compiler giving the error or the browser?

Comment: @E730, the nodeJS server, this is the JS generated from the typescript                   res.end(Buffer.from(body.toString('utf-8'), 'base64'), function(cb){
  print(); or window.print();
});

Comment: the compiler has no issues, its when I run it in a NodeJS server when I click generate the PDF, its returns the data, but when it encounters this function, it fails.

Comment: @E730, updated the query

Comment: I think `window` is not a global in NodeJS: https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html, if you want to print with hardware printer, you can check out a printer module for NodeJS